# Xamarin Forms Teechart - show only graph and labels

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, teechart

I have a steema teechart named tChart1 consisting of candles. I want to show only the candles and the labels of the bottom axis. Everything else should be transparent. I have been able to hide some of the things, but the background is still white and there are vertical lines (I assume the grid) still showing.

```
tChart1.Title.Visible = false;
tChart1.Walls.Visible = false;
tChart1.Axes.Left.Visible = false;
tChart1.Legend.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hide or make transparent the following elements:

```
  tChart1.Axes.Left.Grid.Visible = false;
  tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Grid.Visible = false;

  tChart1.Panel.Transparent = true;
  tChart1.Panel.Gradient.Visible = false;

  tChart1.Walls.Visible = false;
  tChart1.Legend.Transparent = true;
```

Bottom axis labels font color should be changed like this:

```
  tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Font.Color = Color.Blue;
```

Custom labels can be set like this:

```
private void AddCustomLabels()
{
  tChart1.Axes.Left.Labels.Items.Clear();

  (tChart1.Axes.Left.Labels.Items.Add(123,"Hello")).Font.Size=16;
  (tChart1.Axes.Left.Labels.Items.Add(466,"Good\n\rbye")).Transparent=false;
  tChart1.Axes.Left.Labels.Items.Add(300);
  AxisLabelItem a = tChart1.Axes.Left.Labels.Items.Add(-100);
  a.Transparent=false;
  a.Color=Color.Blue;
  a.Transparency=50;
}
```

Candle series pen:

```
  candle1.Pen.Color = Color.Lime;
```

Comment: Thanks! Two follow-up questions: How can I change the color of the labels on the bottom axis and how can I change the color of the candles (not the up or down, but the lines which go through the candle)?

Comment: The label color part doesn't work with me. Does it matter if the labels are added manually through a loop?

Comment: @IliaStoilov are they custom labels? I have extended my reply with custom labels settings as well.

Comment: Your code worked in a test project, but not in the real one. I got it to work with `a.Font.Color = Color.White;`. Thanks for your help, you really saved me!